# html: forcing screen orientation

Tags: android, html, css, responsive-design

I found how to force the horizontal orientation under a certain resolution, and on android work fine, unfortunately it also rotates on the desktop when the window falls within the specific resolution.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  html {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
    width: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

I'm also looking for a way to send mobile phone users to another page where to use this system, but it's also based on the resolution of the device:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "mobile.html";
}
//-->
</script>
```

How can i get forced horizontal orientation only on android and ios (i'm especially for Android)?

or

How can i send these users to another page with forced orientation?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve. To recap, when the desktop user resizes the window to be smaller than 767x766, your page rotates so that it is no longer the right way up, which is a problem, right? But if the same happens when a mobile user wants to look at the page in landscape mode, it's not?

Comment: yes, i want only the landscape orientation on android, and avoid that on desktop could rotate to the wrong way like the css i found

Comment: This is not just dependent on OS but also on browsers and meta tags. Accordingly, 1. what is the browser/s you are testing this on and 2. what are the `meta tags` you are using?

Comment: Safari / chrome on osx, and i see the wrong route within specific size, and android chrome ehich work fine